# Importar dados de uma tabela mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tenho um banco de dados *MySQL* e estou tentando importar os dados de uma tabela que o cliente passou para a minha tabela padrão. Utilizando o *script* abaixo, não aparece erro algum, porém a importação não é feita, a tabela *imoveis* continua vazia:

```
$sql_antigo = "SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id_imovel ASC";
$exe_antigo = mysqli_query($conection, $sql_antigo);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($exe_antigo)){
$id = $row['id_imovel'];
$codigo  = $row['codigo'];
$controle = round(microtime(true) * 1000);

$sql_novo = "INSERT INTO imoveis (id,cod_int,controle) VALUES ('$id','$codigo','$controle')";
$exe_novo = mysqli_query($conection, $sql_novo);

echo 'Dados do imóvel ' .$id. ' importados com sucesso!<br>';
}
```

No *echo*, aparece a frase informando que todos os dados foram importados.

Comment: O `echo`, da forma que está, será exibido independente da tabela ter, ou não, registrado o dado. Utilize o `mysqli_error` para verificar se há erros. Verifique também se o valor de `$exe_antigo` é diferente de `false`

Comment: Podem estar ocorrendo alguns erros no procedimento de Insert.
Como está criada a sua tabela?
Por acaso o campo ID é auto_increment? Se sim, não precisa especificar.
Em $codigo como é um inteiro não precisa das aspas '$codigo' apenas $codigo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso apenas com uma query SQL, vou deixar um exemplo:

Estrutura das tabelas

```
CREATE TABLE `tabela` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `campo1` varchar(255),
  `campo2` varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE `novaTabela` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `campo2` varchar(255),
  `campo1` varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Observe que os `campo1` e `campo2` estão invertidos numa tabela em relação a outra

Dados fictícios

```
INSERT INTO `tabela` (`campo1`,`campo2`) VALUES 
("101","201"),
("102","202"),
("103","203"),
("104","204"),
("105","205"),
("106","206"),
("107","207"),
("108","208"),
("109","209"),
("110","210");
```

A query que resolve o problema

```
INSERT INTO novaTabela SELECT id, campo2, campo1 FROM tabela;
```

Em vez de passar `VALUES (...)` você passa um `SELECT` da tabela onde tem os dados

Observe que em vez de fazer um `SELECT *`, eu selecionei as colunas que eu queria e na ordem que eu queria, assim você pode adequar os dados a nova estrutura. Também pode usar as funções para formatação, por exemplo, transformar um texto em `DateTime`. Como você passa um `SELECT` na inserção, pode usar a cláusula `WHERE` para filrar aquilo que será inserido, tipo, `... WHERE ativo = 1` para adicionar os dados que estão ativos

Comment: O nome dos campos da tabela *A* são diferentes da tabela *B* e provavelmente a estrutura também seja.

Comment: Isso é irrelevante, poderia colocar `campo1`, `foo`, não faria diferença. Como disse pode ser moldado a nova estrutura, provavelmente tudo que seja necessário alterar pode ser feito via SQL, sem nada de PHP ou outra linguagem

Comment: Na pergunta ele cria um número randômico, o MySQL tem uma função pra isso: `RAND()`, que pode ser multiplicado, calculado o quadrado, arrendondado, etc. Tem bastante funções disponíveis

Answer (score -1):

Obrigado pela ajuda, pessoal. Resolvi, mas do modo mais complicado. Gerei um arquivo para importação via phpMyadmin, da seguinte maneira:

echo "INSERT INTO imoveis (codigo,cod_int,controle) 
VALUES 
('0','$id','$controle');
";
}

Colei o resultado no bloco de notas, retirei o último ponto e vírgula e fiz a importação. Deu tudo certo.